How to create a relocatable CMake package that correctly handles the included target directories?
I have realized a Linux library fooLib that provides some functions to be used with alsa-lib data types. I want cmake to configure the compilation of the library and also to create a relocatable package that users of fooLib can import in their CMake project.
The key point (that I am not able to solve) is that the relocatable package should address the correct position of alsa-lib headers in the user machine.
This is my simplified CMakeLists.txt file that relies upon the FindALSA.cmake file shipped with cmake in Ubuntu 22.04  :
project(foo)

find_package(ALSA REQUIRED) # assume that ALSA is found

add_library(fooLib SHARED foo.c) # my source code

target_include_directories(fooLib PUBLIC 
     $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include> # where my foo.h is
     $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include> # where my foo.h will be
     ${ALSA_INCLUDE_DIRS}) # this path is defined after calling find_package(ALSA) and is NOT relocatable

target_link_libraries(fooLib PUBLIC 
    ALSA::ALSA)  # this target is defined after calling find_package(ALSA) and is relocatable

install(TARGETS fooLib EXPORT fooLibTargets)

install(
  EXPORT fooLibTargets
  NAMESPACE fooLib::
  FILE "fooLibTargets.cmake"
  DESTINATION "lib/cmake/fooLib")

The generated fooLibTargets.cmake contains (among others) the following lines:
# Create imported target fooLib::fooLib
add_library(fooLib::fooLib SHARED IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(fooLib::fooLib PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include;/usr/include"
)

This file is not relocatable because the alsa-lib headers path are assumed to be in '/usr/include', which is correct for my machine but non necessarily for the users' one.
How can I overcome this issue and make CMake to generate a relocatable package that correctly handles the included target directories in such situation?
And (possibly), which is the correct approach to generate a relocatable CMake package that does not suffer of this issue? Please note that the official tutorials do not cover this aspect.
Edit:
Please note that removing '/usr/include' does not fix the issue for the users, because they still need to include the path to alsa-lib headers in order to compile.

not directly related to your question but note that target_include_directories(${ALSA_INCLUDE_DIRS} shouldn't be necessary as target_link_libraries(fooLib PUBLIC ALSA::ALSA) should do that for you

Unfortunately, removing target_include_directories(${ALSA_INCLUDE_DIRS} does not fix. It only removes '/usr/include' in INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES but does not replace it with a relocatable string.

Linking with ALSA::ALSA is the correct way: this linkage will be copied into the fooLibTargets.cmake export file. You just need to add call find_dependency(ALSA) into your Config script, so this dependency will be searched on the target machine. The official tutorial actually covers this aspect.

@AlanBirtles After some attempts, I think I got it. You are right, target_include_directories(${ALSA_INCLUDE_DIRS} is unnecessary here. Maybe there is no way to have a relocatable string such that I was asking for, but...there is no need. target_link_libraries(fooLib PUBLIC ALSA::ALSA) does the correct job: it magically sets the include directories for the users of my library when they import its package config file (which I did not report here).
